# Calculate field coordinate in DMS (Degrees Minutes Seconds)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have a point feature class, I want to calculate its latitude and longitude in Degrees Minutes Seconds. The feature class's spatial reference is in PCS (UTM Zone). Is there any way to calculate it using python? I've tried using code
`!SHAPE.CENTROID@DECIMALDEGRESS!.split()[0]` for Longitude, and
`!SHAPE.CENTROID@DECIMALDEGRESS!.split()[1]` for Latitude
It was worked in decimals but it was return to meters unit not in decimal degrees. Now I want to calculate it in DMS.

Any suggest?

My Code is just like this

```
# Add XY Coordinates
arcpy.AddXY_management(LCC_Change_Point)

# Convert Coordinate Notation
arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(LCC_Change_Point, LCC_Change_Point_ConvertCoor, "POINT_X", "POINT_X", "UTM", "DMS", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it wont calculate the coordinates into DD is because you are using a PCS, which will only give you the XY in metres.

Therefore you must use the Convert Coordinate Notation tool which can convert formats of coordinates.

> Converts a table containing point coordinate fields to a point feature class. The input table's coordinate fields can be in a variety of notations, such as GARS, UTM, and MGRS. The output point feature class also contains point coordinate fields in a coordinate notation of your choosing.

Please see the following [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Convert_Coordinate_Notation/0017000000tw000000/) for more information.

To use this in a script, you must first calculate the XY in metres Here, you can use Calulate Field, or the [Add XY Coordinates](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Add_XY_Coordinates/001700000032000000/) tool.
Then, you can use the Convert Coordinate Notation tool which will give you the coordinates into a DMS format.

```
arcpy.AddXY_management(r"path/to/your/dataset")

ConvertCoordinateNotation_management (r"path/to/dataset", "name_of_new_dataset", x_field, y_field, "UTM", "DMS", "OBJECTID", {spatial_reference})
```

Please specify the spatial reference system for the last parameter.

EDIT:

I have added the code you used above and have made corrections. Firstly, the X and Y fields were incorrect. 
Please note how the spatial reference system should have been written: "GCS_WGS_1984". As this is the default for the tool, you dont need to set it as a parameter.

```
# Add XY Coordinates
arcpy.AddXY_management(LCC_Change_Point)

# Convert Coordinate Notation
arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(LCC_Change_Point, LCC_Change_Point_ConvertCoor, "POINT_X", "POINT_Y", "UTM", "DMS")
```

Comment: Is there any way to apply it on python script? Because I want to make an application to update automatically.

Comment: ive added more information above

Comment: Thankyou. But it still give me a warning message. The feature class is created but it's totally blank. No attributes in there. Only headers.

Comment: Whats the warning message? can you update the question with the code that youve used. Im just checking to see if you have added the correct parameters. Run the Add XY first. What are the new X and Y fields?

Comment: in log file, it says:Row with OID: 1 failed
Row with OID: 2 failed
Row with OID: 3 failed
Row with OID: 4 failed
Row with OID: 5 failed
Row with OID: 6 failed
Row with OID: 7 failed
Row with OID: 8 failed
Row with OID: 9 failed
Row with OID: 10 failed

Comment: What about the XY fields that have been added from the Add XY? Can you add the code that you used? Please edit your question, and add this information to it. Please refrain from using the comments section.

Comment: Please see edits above.